# Issue deploying solution of android project on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have to work on an android application using visual studio. So I started by writing a simple "Hello World" application to print on the console.

It gives the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: App1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
1>  App1 -> C:\Users\soume\Desktop\App1\App1\bin\Debug\App1.dll
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
2>Starting deploy VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone ...
2>Starting emulator VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone ...
2>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone -prop monodroid.avdname=VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone
2>PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
2>Emulator VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone cannot be started.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

After looking for *"Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT"* on Google, I thought I may have to set up an environment variable. So I added this to the Path list in System Environmental Variable: `C:\Users\soume\.android\avd`. However, the error has not changed.

Please suggest what is wrong and how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fixed the issue. Opened AVD Manager and edited the AVD named "VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone" found that it did not have a "CPU/ABI" selected and so avd could not be created. Tried with a few different options, and found that "Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64).